# Using a mask vector to filter another vector

Tags: clojure

I have two vectors:

```clj
(def x [true false true]) 
(def y [1 2 3])
```

I'd like to filter `y` based on `x`. My initial attempt is like so:

```clj
(remove nil? (map #(when %1 %2) x y))
```

which returns `(1, 3)` as required.

My question is, is there a way I could have achieved the same result without having to filter out nils at the end? For example, I noticed `keep` removes nils before returning, but it doesn't seem to accept multiple collections, like map does. Is there a more elegant way of filtering using a mask vector like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A vector is an associative collection from indices to items at those indices, so I'd use `reduce-kv`:

```clj
(reduce-kv (fn [result idx item]
             (cond-> result (x idx) (conj item)))
           [] y)
```

There's also `keep-indexed` that you can use as a transducer, but note that this approach will filter out any `nil`s that might be present in the `y` vector:

```clj
(into []
      (keep-indexed (fn [idx item]
                      (when (x idx) item)))
      y)
```

Comment: That's a good point about filtering out nils that were in `y` originally. I think `reduce-kv` is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are right in your observation that there are few other lazy sequence functions beyond `map` that accept multiple collections. The solution that *I find most readable and would reach for first* combines `map` and `for`:

```
(for [[a b] (map vector x y)
      :when a]
  b)
;; => (1 3)
```

In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with using `(map vector ...)` for the purpose of iterating over multiple collections in parallel. The one downside I can see is that we construct short-lived vectors to hold the pairs which could affect performance but you would have to measure that.

If performance is an issue, you may want to look into using a Java iterator using `clojure.lang.RT/iter` (consider it an implementation detail of Clojure) in order to iterate over collections in parallel but this would make your code less pure and it is not the solution I would reach for first.

Here we use it inside a transducer:

```
(into []
      (filter (let [^java.util.Iterator i (clojure.lang.RT/iter x)] 
                 (fn [_] (.next i))))
      y)
;; => [1 3]
```

However, I would be careful combining this iterator approach with *lazy* approaches because it is often a requirement that the predicate is free of side effects.

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many ways.

One thing to note about your initial attempt is that `map` always returns a sequence of the same length as its shortest collection input. So, in your case you'll always get a sequence of length three, hence the need to `remove nil?`.

Here's another attempt with `reduce`:

```clj
user> (def x [true false true]) 
#'user/x
user> (def y [1 2 3])
#'user/y
user> (->> (map-indexed vector y)
           (reduce (fn [eax [i n]] 
                     (if (nth x i) (conj eax n) eax)) 
                   []))
[1 3]
```

---

If you're going to be doing a lot of things with these types of arrays, there are libraries with *very* sharp tools in them for doing this kind of thing extremely efficently:

```
user> (require '[tech.v3.datatype.unary-pred :as un-pred])
nil
user> (un-pred/bool-reader->indexes x)
[0 2]
user> (def idxs *1)
#'user/idxs
user> (require '[tech.v3.tensor :as dtt])
nil
user> (dtt/select y idxs)
#tech.v3.tensor<object>[2]
[1 3]
```

c.f., https://github.com/cnuernber/dtype-next

Answer (score 2):

you could also do something like this:

`(mapcat #(when %1 [%2]) x y)`

shouldn't be much worse from performance point of view comparing to the rest of answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have always missed the `zip` function from Python when using Clojure, so I wrote my own implementation.  It is so handy when using `reduce` or similar functions:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]))

(def x [true false true])
(def y [1 2 3])

(def zipped (t/zip x y))

(verify
  (is= zipped
    [[true 1]
     [false 2]
     [true 3]])

  (let [result (reduce
                 (fn [cum [flag value]]
                   (if flag
                     (t/append cum value)
                     cum))
                 []
                 zipped)]
    (is= result [1 3])))
```

You could simplify a bit more as so:

```
(verify
  (let [result (reduce
                 (fn [cum [flag value]]
                   (t/cond-it-> cum
                     flag (t/append it value)))
                 []
                 zipped)]
    (is= result [1 3])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer similar to @Rulle's list comprehension, but in plain Clojure:

```
(defn mask [values mask-vector]
  (->> (mapv vector values mask-vector)
       (filter second)
       (mapv first)))
```

test:

```
(mask [1 2 3] [true false true])
```

which returns:

```
[1 3]
```

QED